# Please what could be the solution here?, the issue is the space between my name "Samuel Oniyilo" in the image

Tags: css, whitespace

```
#dent {
  background-image: url(C:\Users\Samuel Oniyilo\Documents\GitHub\hng-wonderwoman-task-1\hngi7-task2-HearthHotels\images\black-rotary-telephone-beside-ball-pen-on-white-printed-47319.jpg); 
  background-size: 1350px 600px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  filter: blur(0.2px);
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 150px;
  font-size: large;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  padding-top : 1px;
}
```

Please what could be the solution here? I realized the issue is the space between my name "Samuel Oniyilo" in the image.There anything that can represent the space in a css style

Comment: Please share a working example maybe in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the path in "quotations".

```
background-image: url("C:\Users\Samuel Oniyilo\Documents\GitHub\hng-wonderwoman-task-1\hngi7-task2-HearthHotels\images\black-rotary-telephone-beside-ball-pen-on-white-printed-47319.jpg");
```